# ArrayList not showing last item in listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am storing values in arraylist as`{india,pakisthan,srilanka,nepal,malasiya,australia,ireland}` when I set this list to `BaseAdapter` the last element is not showing last item in `listview` when listview extends device screen. It showing only India, Pakisthan, Srilanka, Nepal, Malasiaya and Australia was breaking and Ireland was not showing. My `ListFragment` class is

```
package com.example.mynavigationtab;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class AndroidFragment  extends ListFragment
{
ArrayList<CountryObject> mCountry = new ArrayList<CountryObject>();
ArrayList<String> mCoun = new ArrayList<String>();
CountryObject country = new CountryObject();
AndroidAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     LoadUrl();
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
public void LoadUrl()
{
ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("naren", "naren"));
new GetJsonData().execute(getString(R.string.tag_url),pairs,ThreadCode.THREAD_URL, handler);
}
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    getActivity().removeDialog(0);
    switch (msg.what) {
    case ThreadCode.THREAD_URL:
        final String result = (String) msg.obj;
        LoadJson(result);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
};
public void LoadJson(String result)
{
try
{
    JSONObject mJson1 = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray mResult = mJson1.getJSONArray("result");
    mCountry = new ArrayList<CountryObject>();
    for(int i=0; i<mResult.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject mRes = mResult.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray mCount = mRes.getJSONArray("Country");

            JSONObject mCoun = mCount.getJSONObject(i);
            CountryObject mSetData = new CountryObject();
            mSetData.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData);
            CountryObject mSetData1 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData1.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name1"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData1);
            CountryObject mSetData2 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData2.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name2"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData2);
            CountryObject mSetData3 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData3.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name3"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData3);
            CountryObject mSetData4 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData4.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name4"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData4);
            CountryObject mSetData5 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData5.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name5"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData5);
            CountryObject mSetData6 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData6.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name6"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData6);
            CountryObject mSetData7 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData7.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name7"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData7);
            CountryObject mSetData8 = new CountryObject();
            mSetData8.setmCountry(mCoun.getString("name8"));
            mCountry.add(mSetData8);
        }       
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    String mMessage = "Error parsing JSON data from server. Please try again.";
    showToast(mMessage);
}
}
public void showToast(String message) {
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, duration);
toast.show();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
LoadUrl();


}
   }`
```

**//Adapter class**

```
package com.example.mynavigationtab;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
ArrayList<String> mCountry = new ArrayList<String>();
Context mContext;
TextView mCountryName;
public AndroidAdapter(Context androidFragment,ArrayList<String> mCoun) 
{
    mCountry = mCoun;
    mContext = androidFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return mCountry.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return mCountry.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return mCountry.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
converview = null;
       if (convertView == null) 
       {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list, parent,false);
         mCountryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textOne);
         mCountryName.setText(mCountry.get(position));
       }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

// Xml Layout for adapter_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textOne"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:padding="2dp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>


//Json File
{
result: [
{
Country: [
{
name: "India",
name1: "Pakisthan",
name2: "Bangaldesh",
name3: "Australia",
name4: "Ireland",
name5: "SriLanka",
name6: "Nepal",
name7: "USA",
name8: "Russia"
}
],
States: [
{
states: "Tamil Nadu",
states1: "Andhra",
states2: "Karnataka",
states3: "Kerala"
}
],
District: [
{
district: "Krishnagiri",
district1: "Dharmapuri",
district2: "Salem",
district3: "Hosur"
}
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: First, check in your adapter constructor to see if the data -thourgh mCount ArrayList- is actually received.

Comment: in for loop use i<=mCountry.size() insted i<mCountry.size() n try. hope its works

Comment: Maybe the problem is the layout (cause only half item is shown). Show it. I think "return mCountry.indexOf(getItem(position));" equals "return position;"

Comment: Are you seeing any vertical scrolls? Are you saying that all items not shown at a single stretch?

Comment: In portrait it showing all items. But, in Landscape the last item is not showing.....  Dinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I solved it.............
The Problem is in my xml layout. That i have mentioned a weight for framelayout in TabHost

//Modified xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DBE9F4">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_shape"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
May this solve your problem :
if (convertView == null) 
       {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.adapter_list, parent,false);
         mCountryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textOne);

       }

mCountryName.setText(mCountry.get(position));//Write this after condition
```

Comment: Print your arraylist in your logcat, i think so data is not stored properly in the arraylist

Comment: Logcat result loading first time displays '10-06 12:43:20.537: I/Arraylits(4054): India
10-06 12:43:20.547: I/Arraylits(4054): Pakisthan
10-06 12:43:20.567: I/Arraylits(4054): Bangaldesh
10-06 12:43:20.607: I/Arraylits(4054): Australia
10-06 12:43:20.607: I/Arraylits(4054): Ireland
10-06 12:43:20.637: I/Arraylits(4054): SriLanka
' then scrolling displays '10-06 12:43:32.268: I/Arraylits(4054): Nepal
' remaining two items not displaying

Comment: ArrayList contains '10-06 12:54:38.978: V/array(4102): [India, Pakisthan, Bangaldesh, Australia, Ireland, SriLanka, Nepal, USA, Russia]
'

Comment: Yon can post me your jsonresponse ??

Comment: This is my Json File:{
result: [
{
Country: [
{
name: "India",
name1: "Pakisthan",
name2: "Bangaldesh",
name3: "Australia",
name4: "Ireland",
name5: "SriLanka",
name6: "Nepal",
name7: "USA",
name8: "Russia"
}
],
States: [
{
states: "Tamil Nadu",
states1: "Andhra",
states2: "Karnataka",
states3: "Kerala"
}
],
District: [
{
district: "Krishnagiri",
district1: "Dharmapuri",
district2: "Salem",
district3: "Hosur"
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: So why are you putting json parsing into loop?? , no need of for loop

Comment: Then how to use without loop

Comment: remove for loop and try it , it will do

Comment: Where in Getdata() method or LoadData() method

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're setting the text only when `convertView` is null. You should make sure that the line `mCountryName.setText(mCountry.get(position));` is executed every single time, otherwise some items will not show up.

Comment: Its getting nine items out of nine but displaying only seven and eight item shows only half and ninth not showing..... how to solve this, please help me.... thanks advance